(co)limit diagram of derived stacks can be checked fiberwise
In the category of stacks, the (co)limit diagram can be checked by taking the fiber, then the (co)limit condition reduces to a diagram in the 2-category $Grpd$.
I am not very familiar with the derived algebraic geometry, and I am wondering whether this is also true for the derived stacks $F: SCRing \rightarrow Spc= Grpd_{\infty}$.
For instance, can a (co)cartesian diagram be checked by taking fiber $F(A)$ for all the derived stacks involved in this diagram, where $A$ is an arbitrary object in the infinite category $SCRing$?

Derived stacks form a reflective subcategory of the (∞,1)-category of (∞,1)-presheaves on a given site.  This implies that (∞,1)-limits of derived stacks are computed objectwise, whereas (∞,1)-colimits of derived stacks are computed by taking the associated (∞,1)-sheaf of the objectwise (∞,1)-colimit.
In particular, objectwise (co)cartesian squares of (∞,1)-stacks are indeed (co)cartesian squares.
